# Recover deleted repository on disk SourceTree

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, file-recovery, sourcetree

I was trying to delete my repositories in sourcetree but inadvertently deleted all the files and code within the repository,

I have seen a very similar question asked once before but the solution was not answered or commented,

Any possible solutions will be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Now SourceTree will send deleted files to the recycle bin. So you can find them back.

Comment: Tried many things but lost hope! It is too simple :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution,

After extensive research I found out that i cannot recover the files as i only created local copies of the repositories on sourcetree and never actually made an online repository on bitbucket.